# decision tree for predictive modelling

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, supervised-learning

I have a satellite data that provides radiance which i  use to compute Flux (using surface and cloud info). Now using a regression method, I can have a mathematical model relating radiance and flux and can be used to predict the flux for new radiance values without the other new inputs.

Is it possible to do same using decision trees or regression trees..? In a regression there is mathematical equation connecting dependent and independent variable. using decision trees, how you develop such a model?

Comment: If what you are asking is whether or not there is a distinct mathematical model that directly relates features to the target variable, then I don't believe so. Decision/regression trees are usually calculated recursively using some form of entropy/Information Gain framework. It may (I'm no expert on this) be possible to use the outputs/rules of a decision/regression tree to form a mathematical model

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you ask this in [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com). A simple global regression model is a special case of a regression tree where there is only one node, so you can definitely apply regression tree for your data. Decision trees are generally used for classification, not regression.